# How to formulate an ODE for discrete iterative algorithm?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods

Consider an iterative algorithm of the type $$x_{k+1} = x_{k}-c \cdot \alpha^k \nabla f(x_{k}),$$ where $f$ is some function and $\alpha>0, \:c=constant$. Also, $k$ in $\alpha^k$ is taken to be an exponent rather than an index (i.e. we have an exponential step-size which is supposed to decrease as $k$ increases and ultimately vanish when $k \to \infty$).

I want to derive a corresponding continuous-time ordinary differential equation for the same. I have tried different heuristics relating iteration number $k$ with time $t$ but not able to make any good progress.

Could someone point me to the resources or methods used for this kind of conversion from discrete to continuous time. In addition, I would also like to study the uniqueness and existence for solutions of  the obtained differential equation, which (I guess) would be something of this form $$a(t)\ddot{X}(t)+b(t)\dot{X}(t)+c(t)\nabla f(X(t)=0$$
Please provide references (preferably short monographs or books) for that as well. Thanks!

Comment: In this context there are two valid interpretation of the symbol $\alpha^k$. The number $k$ is either an index or an exponent. You should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks @CarlChristian for pointing that out. Here k in $\alpha^k$ represents an exponent.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is large enough, so that $α^k$ is small, then the iteration approximately follows the solution curves of $$\dot x=-∇f(x),$$ the gradient flow. To get the relation of time and index $k$, you just need to sum up some geometric sequences for $t_{k+1}-t_k=h_k=cα^k$, so that $$t_k=t_0+c\frac{1-α^k}{1-α}.$$

This suggests that your approach may converge to some point away from the minimum, as in the linearization around the extremal point $x_*$ the path is approximately $\dot x=-H_f (x-x_*)$, $H_f$ the Hessean matrix at $x_*$, so that $$x(t)=x_*+\exp(-H_ft)x(t_0),$$ which has a finite distance to $x_*$ for $t=t_\infty = t_0+\frac{c}{1-α}$.

---

In general it gets fast to rather complicated expressions if you want to switch from a discrete to a continuous model. If the steps in the discrete model are large and chaotic, which may happen here in the global phase where the iterates are far away from a minimum, it is impossible to give a continuous model that only halfway captures the discrete behavior. Sometimes this question is asked about the Henon map.

When the steps are small, you can consider the discrete steps as Euler method. However, reconstruction to any higher order involves higher derivatives of the step function. Comparing $$x_{n+1}=x_n+hF(x_n)$$ with 
$$
x(t+h)=x(t)+h\dot x+\frac{h^2}2\ddot x+...\\
=x(t)+hF_h(x(t))+\frac{h^2}2F_h'(x(t))F_h(x)+...
$$
leads to the second order approximation $F_h(x)=F(x)-\frac{h}{2}F'(x)F(x)$, here $F_h(x)=-∇f(x)-\frac{h}2H_f(x)∇f(x)$. In the linearization this now has the matrix $-H_f-\frac h2 H_f^2$ which does not change that the time steps end at a finite time.

---

As a demonstrative example of the perturbation idea, using the circle equation for $F$ and step size $h=0.2$, this gives for 100 Euler steps the following spiral that is closely followed by the "exact" numerical solution of the perturbed equation.
[image]

Comment: Hi Lutz, I've clarified certain things in the problem. Could you please let me know your thoughts on the modified problem. Also, when you say sum-up geometric sequences what do you exactly mean? could you please elaborate a little. Thanks!